# Pointer pointing to itself

Tags: c, pointers

I was exploring typedefs and stumbled upon this program

**EDIT**: Nearly all the answers were concerned about the warnings it generates. So, I went ahead and removed all the warnings but the question remains the same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int int3[3];
int main(){
    int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5}};
    int3 *p = a;
    int *ip = (int *) a;
    printf("sizeof:\np: %lu\n(*p+0): %lu\n**p: %lu\nip: %lu\n*ip: %lu\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
    printf("---\n");
    printf("p: %p\tp+1: %p\n*p: %p\t*p+1: %p\n**p: %d\nip: %p\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
    return 0;
}
```

on one run it shows:

```
sizeof:
p: 8
(*p+0): 8
**p: 4
ip: 8
*ip: 4
---
p: 0x7ffe36df31b0   p+1: 0x7ffe36df31bc
*p: 0x7ffe36df31b0  *p+1: 0x7ffe36df31b4
**p: 1
ip: 0x7ffe36df31b0
*ip: 1
```

My question is:
If p and *p are equal
and **p = 1
then why not *p = 1 as well ?

Provided size of pointer = 8 and size of int = 4
   Even if taking in account pointer arithmetic, then *p should at least be 0xkk kk kk kk 00 00 00 01
   k being any hex number (consider little-endian)
   because de-referencing the same address as int should give 1

**EDIT**:
To make things clearer, consider this table:

```
+-----------+----------------------+------------------+
|Variable   | Value                | Address          |
|           |                      |                  |
|           |                      |                  |
| p         | 0x7ffe36df31b0       |                  |
|           |                      |                  |
|*p         | 0x7ffe36df31b0       |  0x7ffe36df31b0  |
|           |                      |                  |
|**p        | 1                    |  0x7ffe36df31b0  |
+-----------+----------------------+------------------+
```

How can *p and **p have same address but different value ?

Comment: please compile with warnings enabled and then edit your code to remove the warnings

Comment: P is pointing at a 2 dimensional array. Essentially a pointer to a pointer. So * p gives you the address of the array {1,2,3}, p[0], while ** p is nearly equivalent to p[0][0].

Comment: Don't use `%x` to print the value of a pointer, use `%p`.

Comment: Also `*p + 0` is nonsense. Or it isn't but doesn't tell anything

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `*p`, by itself represents an array. As per rules, `sizeof` operator doesn't convert the array name to a pointer. `+0` turns it into a pointer.

Comment: @138 If *p gives the address of array {1,2,3} to which it points, then why does p also give the same address ? Doesn't p point to a multi D array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that this code in a confusing mish-mash of constraint violations combined with [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to generate output of questionable usefulness.  But I'll try to answer your question as to what's going on, and try using mundane explanations without resorting to citations from the C Standard, as others already have answered in that manner.

> How can *p and **p have same address but different value ?

Because `p` is a pointer to an array.

Given

```
typedef int int3[3];
int3 *p;
```

that means `*p` is a three-dimensional array.  Note that

```
int3 *p = a;
```

is a constraint violation, as noted elsewhere.  You can *force* that to "work" with a cast, but it's still fundamentally wrong and the code only "gets away" with it because the address of an array is the address of the first element of that array - **and** your current implementation doesn't differentiate the pointer types in a significant-enough fashion they they're fundamentally incompatible.  Pick an implementation where a plain `int *` is, say, a 32-bit offset value while an array would have as its address both a 32-bit segment **and** a 32-bit offset value, and the code would likely generate nonsense if it didn't fail utterly.  That's why the C Standard requires pointers to be to "compatible types" - because pointers don't have to be compatible at all.

That problem aside, the initialization/assignment on your implementation can seemingly be treated as

```
int3 *p = ( int3 * ) a;
```

Since that "works", that means `p` contains the address of a three-element array of `int` values.  So dereferencing `p` with `*p` is the same as `a[0]`, or the first three-element `int` array in the two-dimensional `a` array.

So what is `*p`, then?

It's exactly the same in this case as `a[0]`, an array.  And such a bare array reference [decays to an address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)*, and that address is of the same **type** as a pointer to an element of the array.  And the value of that address will be that of the address of the first element of the array.

So `*p`, which is a three-element array of `int`, can itself be dereferenced and evaluate to the first element of `a[0]`, or `a[0][0]`.  So `**p` is the same as `a[0][0]`.

And `a[0][0]` - or `**p` - is an `int` that is initialized with the value of `1`.

While `*p` is `a[0]` and the **address** of that first element.

* - A lot of people say an array "decays to a pointer" or "an array is a pointer", but I like "decays to an address" because a pointer can be assigned to but an address simply **is** - it can't be assigned to itself, just like an array itself can't be assigned to, but the address can be assigned to something else, like a pointer.  Note than when an array is passed to a function, the **address** of the array actually is passed as an actual pointer.  The pointer is the function's parameter and that function parameter can be assigned to...

Answer (score 1):

the posted code, when compiled with:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11
```

results in the following compiler messages:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c"  (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:6:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int *ip = a;
               ^
untitled.c:7:26: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                         ~^
                         %ld
untitled.c:7:38: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                     ~^
                                     %ld
untitled.c:7:47: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                              ~^
                                              %ld
untitled.c:7:55: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                                      ~^
                                                      %ld
untitled.c:7:64: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 6 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                                               ~^
                                                               %ld
untitled.c:9:17: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[3]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                ~^
untitled.c:9:26: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int (*)[3]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                         ~^                                                ~~~
untitled.c:9:34: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                 ~^
                                 %ls
untitled.c:9:44: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                           ~^                                     ~~~~
                                           %ls
untitled.c:9:61: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 7 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                                            ~^
                                                            %ls
Compilation finished successfully.
```

The compiler finishes up by saying the compilation was successful.  That does NOT mean that it is ok to run this code and expect valid results/output.

When you correct the code so it cleanly compiles, then please post a EDIT to your question that contains the modified/corrected code.

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c"  (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:6:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int *ip = a;
               ^
untitled.c:7:26: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                         ~^
                         %ld
untitled.c:7:38: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                     ~^
                                     %ld
untitled.c:7:47: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                              ~^
                                              %ld
untitled.c:7:55: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                                      ~^
                                                      %ld
untitled.c:7:64: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 6 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof:\np: %d\n(*p+0): %d\n**p: %d\nip: %d\n*ip: %d\n",sizeof p, sizeof (*p+0), sizeof **p, sizeof ip, sizeof *ip);
                                                               ~^
                                                               %ld
untitled.c:9:17: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[3]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                ~^
untitled.c:9:26: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int (*)[3]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                         ~^                                                ~~~
untitled.c:9:34: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                 ~^
                                 %ls
untitled.c:9:44: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                           ~^                                     ~~~~
                                           %ls
untitled.c:9:61: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 7 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("p: %x\tp+1: %x\n*p: %x\t*p+1: %x\n**p: %d\nip: %x\n*ip: %d",p,p+1,*p,*p+1,**p,ip,*ip);
                                                            ~^
                                                            %ls
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Comment: The question is not about the warnings but the language's definition.

Comment: @Hritik of course it is about the warnings: each and every warning there is about the language definition that you broke.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is constraint violation because you are using incompatible pointer types in the following initialization:

```
int *ip = a;
```

As per C11 standard section on [Pointer declarators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1p2)

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

and on [Simple assignment/Constraints](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1)

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

The compiler is require to emit a diagnostic in this case which it does:

> ```
> <source>:8:15: warning: initialization of 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
>      int *ip = a;
> ```

See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s87bxA)

When you compile a program, it is good practice to enable all warnings and treat warnings as errors so as to avoid (as far as possible) this kind of behavior.

Comment: The behaviour is not undefined *there*, but it is constraint violation, so a compiler **must** issue a diagnostics message.

Comment: That's what I thought too at first. But found the quote in the Annex. Please let me know if my interpretation of the quote is wrong.

Comment: The annex is not normative. In addition, there is a clause [C11 5.1.1.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.3p1) *" A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, **even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.**"*

Comment: [6.7.9p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11) says that the semantic rules of initialization are the same as for simple assignment and simple assignment says in constraints that the pointers must be compatible

Comment: Thank you. I have revised the answer as per your inputs. Just curious to know: If the annex on undefined behavior is not normative , does it mean that the compiler can make some of the points listed there *defined* behavior? In that case, is the compiler required to document it?

Comment: Does that mean conversion between pointers is not defined by the language ?

Comment: @Hritik yes, it is defined, It is defined that you must use a *cast* (explicit conversion)